# Perl scoping and the life of local variables

Tags: perl, lexical-scope

How long does the memory location allocated by a local variable in Perl live for (both for arrays, hashes and scalars)? For instance:

```
sub routine
{  
  my $foo = "bar";  
  return \$foo;  
}
```

Can you still access the string `"bar"` in memory after the function has returned? How long will it live for, and is it similar to a static variable in C or more like a variable declared off the heap?

Basically, does this make sense in this context?

```
$ref = routine()  
print ${$ref};
```

Comment: Did you try this code? You could have at least answered the first question yourself.

Comment: @runrig, there's a difference between "it happens to work in this particular case" and "this is actually supposed to work".  Running the code will only tell you the first.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, that code will work fine.

Perl uses [reference counting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting), so the variable will live as long as somebody has a reference to it.  Perl's [lexical variables](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Private-Variables-via-my%28%29) are sort of like C's automatic variables, because they normally go away when you leave the scope, but they're also like a variable on the heap, because you can return a reference to one and it will just work.

They're not like C's static variables, because you get a new `$foo` every time you call `routine` (even recursively).  (Perl 5.10 introduced [`state` variables](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Persistent-Private-Variables), which are rather like a C static.)